# How to retrive mails from previous hosting server?

Tags: email, smtp

I am moving from my current web hosting provider to another. I have moved my whole website completely but the problem I am facing is how to move mails as well. Both the hosting servers are UNIX servers so my question is "Is there any mechanism or command to move the mails as we move files ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do both your providers provide an IMAP service?  If so, use an IMAP capable mail reader with accounts configured for both providers and copy mail from one to the other.

Comment: The easier way is tell all users to download all their email.Let old hosting email is empty.

Comment: you can perhaps do a file copy (eg using rsync) if both servers are using the same format.

Comment: @scott, I gave another solution for him.He can follow my solution or not? Anything wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **IMAP**, there is something called **IMAPSync** and it will help you through the migration. If you are using CentOS or RHEL 7, You can download it from **epel** repository by doing the following commands:

```
$ yum -y install epel-release && yum -y install imapsync
```

**NOTE**: if you're using Debian, or FreeBSD, check out this [installation help](https://imapsync.lamiral.info/#install).

It is not so hard to work with it, it is so clear and you can read its manual pages or surf the net for examples, or easily read its own docs provided in its [Official WebPage](https://imapsync.lamiral.info).

For a quick insight, take a look at the examples below:

### ● Single MailBox Migration

```
### OR WITH PASSWORD FILE ↴

$ imapsync\
--host1 server1.example.com --user1 x@example.com --passfile1 /path/to/secret/file\
--host2 server2.example.com --user2 x@example.com --passfile2 /path/to/secret/file

### OR WITH PLAIN-TEXT PASSWORD ↴

$ imapsync\
--host1 server1.example.com --user1 x@example.com --password1 PASSWORD\
--host2 server2.example.com --user2 x@example.com --password2 PASSWORD
```

The example above, will transfer emails from User1 in Host1 to User2 in Host2 via password file or a plain text password.

### ● Huge Migration

If you are dealing with a huge amount of users, you can create a file called *file.txt* or whatsoever, that holds users and passwords: (the separator is ";")

```
user001_1;password001_1;user001_2;password001_2
user002_1;password002_1;user002_2;password002_2
user003_1;password003_1;user003_2;password003_2
user004_1;password004_1;user004_2;password004_2
user005_1;password005_1;user005_2;password005_2 ...
```

Now you can do the transfer job via a shell script including the lines below:

```
 { while IFS=';' read  u1 p1 u2 p2; do
        imapsync --host1 imap.side1.org --user1 "$u1" --password1 "$p1" \
                 --host2 imap.side2.org --user2 "$u2" --password2 "$p2" ...
 done ; } < file.txt
```

For further information on migration methods, I recommend you read [IMAPSync in GitHub](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) or check out its [Official WebPage](https://imapsync.lamiral.info).

---

**N.B**: Emails sent and received within and whilst using the old provider (Host1 in our examples) will include the old addresses (as they should so), so if your domain is changed or email addresses are changed, you should notify your users so as they will not get confused.